# slider on continuous loop

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I have created a review section which is trigged on click, what I want to achieve is that when the last review appears the first review appears after- a continuous cycle.

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/melissaboyle19/kvVC7/)

```
/* Set global variables */
var position = $(".reviews").position(); /* Find position of review container */
var items = $(".reviews ul li").length; /* Count how many reviews there are */
var limit = (items - 2) * -435; /* Set the movement limit as a multiple of the number of items */

$(".number").text(items);

/* Next button clicked */
$(".btn_next").click(function () {

position = $(".reviews").position();

/* Debugging Info */
/* $(".left").text(Position: " + position.left + " & " + "Items: " + items  + " & " + "Limit: " + limit); */

/* If the review container’s left value is still larger than the movement limit, move the container one view to the left */
if (position.left > limit) {
    $(".reviews").animate({
        "left": "-=460px"
    }, 500, "swing");
} else {
    /* $(".left").prepend("No dice! "); */
}

});

/* Prev button clicked */
$(".btn_prev").click(function () {

    position = $(".reviews").position();

    /* Debugging Info */
    /* $(".left").text("Position: " + position.left + " & " + "Items: " + items  + " & " + "Limit: " + limit); */

    /* If the review container’s left value is still smaller than 0, move the container one view to the right */
    if (position.left < 0) {
        $(".reviews").animate({
            "left": "+=460px"
        }, 500, "swing");

} else {
    /* $(".left").prepend("No dice! "); */
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is, when the user press left and it's already at the left, scroll to the right.

It don't show the review in a loop, but it loop when you press the arrow.

Example:

```
if (position.left < 0) {
    $(".reviews").animate({
        "left": "+=460px"
    }, 500, "swing");

} else {
    var restartPos = 460 * (items-2);
    $(".reviews").animate({
        "left": "-="+restartPos+"px"
    }, 500, "swing");
}
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KGkg/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you have to do some small changes to your code.
to roll left to the last item instead of

```
if (position.left > limit) {
    $(".reviews").animate({
           "left": "-=460px"
    }, 500, "swing");
} else {
    /* $(".left").prepend("No dice! "); */
}
```

put this:

```
if (position.left > limit) {
    val = "-=460";
} else {  
    val = 8;
}
$(".reviews").animate({
        "left": val + 'px'
}, 500, "swing");
```

to roll right to the first item item instead of:

```
if (position.left < 0) {
    $(".reviews").animate({
        "left": "+=460px"
    }, 500, "swing");
} else {
    /* $(".left").prepend("No dice! "); */
}
```

put this:

```
if (position.left < 0) {
    val = "+=460"
} else {
    val = (items - 2) * (-460);
}
$(".reviews").animate({
        "left": val + 'px'
}, 500, "swing");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kvVC7/3/